# How to include scripts from gutenberg plugin subfolders

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm setting up a plugin for my custom gutenberg blocks. Each block has is own registering script (`blocks/block1/block.php`). I want to call/include each registering script from the main plugin file (`blocks-plugin.php`).

The folder structure is as following:

- (blocks-plugin)

  - blocks-plugin.php
  - (blocks)

    - (block1)

      - block.php
      - block.js
    - (block2)

      - block.php
      - block.js

I tried the `require`/`include` and the `require_once`/`include_once` commands, but the path to the script gets doubled in some way:

**Input:**

`blocks-plugin.php`:

```
defined('ABSPATH') || die;
require dirname(__FILE__) . '/blocks/block1/block.php';
```

`blocks/block1/block.php`:

```
defined('ABSPATH') || die;
wp_register_script(
    'block1',
    plugins_url('/blocks/filter-posts/block.js', __FILE__),
    array( 'wp-blocks', 'wp-element' ) //dependencies
);
```

**Output:**

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wp- content/plugins/blocks-plugin/blocks/block1/blocks/block1/block.js'></script>
```

I can't figure out, what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: figured it out: `plugins_url('/block.js', __FILE__),`